# STRIPE Extention (ver. 6.7.13) : Recurring contributions are no longer activated

Tags: recurring-contributions, stripe

Starting from one of the latest extention updates (ver. 6.7.13 or 6.7.12), recurring contributions are no longer activated (1shot payment works correctly)

The problem is detailed here: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/399

Another NPO, which a similar setup but older API version, has the same problem: At the end of the process, already during the double authentication, the correct value is not transferred (but the value €0.00 is transferred) and the recurring donation is not activated.

Anyone having the same problems as us to activate new recurring donations with Stripe?

- CiviCRM ver. 5.55.2  (also 5.52.3 or 5.53)
- Stripe Payment Processor 6.7.13
- Wordpress 6.1.1
- PHP 7.4.33
- Stripe API version 2022-11-15
- all Stripe "subscription events" (in webhook) are actived